# Lead conversion to account missing field data

Tags: lightning, field-update, lead-conversion

Is it an issue in Lightning in Spring '17 that the field data from the Lead is not auto-populated in to the Account during lead conversion?

Comment: We'll need to see some code, I think. I'm not aware of a Known Issue with conversion. What have you observed versus what you've expected?

Comment: on testing, it looks like data is getting copied into the mapped fields correctly, the true issue is only that the data does show in the account fields in the conversation screen when selecting "+ New Account"